# Gerrit web interface: add multiple reviewers

Tags: gerrit

Using the Gerrit web interface, is it possible to add multiple reviewers at once to a given commit? Currently, it appears that reviewers have to be added one by one: trying to add a list as input fails regardless of how it is separated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it isn't possible to add multiple reviewers at once using Gerrit UI. You have to add one by one or use REST like in this example:

```
curl --request POST -d@- --header Content-Type:application/json https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/changes/CHANGE-NUMBER/reviewers << EOF
{
    "reviewer": "USERNAME1",
    "reviewer": "USERNAME2"
}
EOF
```

Comment: Yes, turns out this is how it is. Myself, I ended up using the Gerrit plugin for IntelliJ which has the feature I was looking for built in.

Comment: How to use above example  in gerrit?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can not add multiple reviewers at once using Gerrit UI.
You can create a Group under **"People" -> "Crete New Group"** and add the required list of members to be reviewers in that group.

Use the **"Group Name"** while adding reviewers

[image: Create New Group]